# Bash: Execute command independent of parent PID?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu, process

Executing this `test.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 15 & sleep 2000
```

Then, viewing the running processes with `$ ps auxfwww | grep -i [2]000 -B 10`, I get the following `11886` and `11887` PIDs:

```
user      7070  0.0  0.0   4504  1444 ?        Ss   Nov15   0:00          \_ /bin/sh /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc
user      7081  0.0  0.0 324540 14064 ?        Sl   Nov15   0:00          |   \_ xfce4-session
user      7100  0.0  0.3 562128 62800 ?        Sl   Nov15   0:48          |       \_ tilix
user     23644  0.0  0.0  31132  6136 pts/11   Ss   14:32   0:00          |       |   \_ /bin/bash
user     11884  0.0  0.0  20024  3044 pts/11   S+   14:58   0:00          |       |   |   \_ /bin/bash ./test.sh
user     11886  0.0  0.0  14776   700 pts/11   S+   14:58   0:00          |       |   |       \_ sleep 15
user     11887  0.0  0.0  14776   704 pts/11   S+   14:58   0:00          |       |   |       \_ sleep 2000
```

Is it possible to execute the `sleep 2000` command entirely independent of the parent processes? For example:

```
user      7070  0.0  0.0   4504  1444 ?        Ss   Nov15   0:00          \_ /bin/sh /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc
user      7081  0.0  0.0 324540 14064 ?        Sl   Nov15   0:00          |   \_ xfce4-session
user      7100  0.0  0.3 562128 62800 ?        Sl   Nov15   0:48          |   |   \_ tilix
user     23644  0.0  0.0  31132  6136 pts/11   Ss   14:32   0:00          |   |   |   \_ /bin/bash
user     11884  0.0  0.0  20024  3044 pts/11   S+   14:58   0:00          |   |   |   |   \_ /bin/bash ./test.sh
user     11886  0.0  0.0  14776   700 pts/11   S+   14:58   0:00          |   |   |   |       \_ sleep 15
user     XXXXX  0.0  0.0  XXXXX   XXX XXXXXX   S+   XX:XX   0:00          \_ sleep 2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

What you want here is for the process to be reparented. Unix will reparent process to PID 1 once their original parent processes terminate.

So all you need to do is to have the *original* parent of the `sleep 2000` exit.

You can do that by launching the background `sleep 2000` from a subshell.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 15 &
( sleep 2000 & )
# do something else here, like:
sleep 1
echo "=== Listing 'sleep' process tree: ==="
ps auxfwww | grep -i [2]000 -B 10
echo "=== All done. ===
```

Comment: thanks so much. This method doesnt seem to work with variables, for example: `$ var="/bin/sleep";( eval $var 2000 & )`

Comment: It works if you don't use `eval` (which you don't really need.) Just use the variable directly. And, for correctness, you should quote it: `var=/bin/sleep; ( "$var" 2000 & )`.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused; the question and the answer talk about PPID, but that's not part of the output of `ps auxfwww` at all?

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger maybe you can assist with this one as well? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482431/

Comment: @tink see the alignment of the sleep in the process tree. Being in the first level suggests to me that it's intended to be right under init...