# Bash: Use raw binary in variable as executable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, variable

I'd like to create a variable containing binary data, then execute in a command. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
var="$(cat /bin/sleep)"
"$var" 9999
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot execute a variable like that because:

- the kernel executes files,
- the shell can execute command lines stored in variables, but it cannot interpret binary data
- storing a binary file's contents in a variable will likely not work well, because null bytes may be present in the file (and you can't have null bytes in variables of most shells)
- even if you used process substitution to get a temporary file with the contents of that variable, process substitution file handles won't be executable

So you'll have to store the contents in a file, make that file executable, hope that nothing got missed because of a null bytes, and execute that file.